# PHP session_start() fails with warning

Tags: php, session

My PHP site suddenly stops working with error of

`Warning: session_start(): open(/tmp/sess_3cd2b95bda289919f7993a8eaf6bc1c9, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /home/`

I found info to fix it from StackOverflow that by adding `ini_set('session.save_path', 'tmp');` before session_start(); but I have to do this on every page, as there are so many pages. Is there any possible way to declare a global variable or any other way so that I don't have to add this on every page on my website?

Comment: ini_set is for RUNTIME overrides. you need to change the setting in php.ini, so it applies to ALL scripts - e.g.a  permanent setting.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried to searched php.ini in whole folder of site but can't find it at all.